# jQuery MultiSelectors With Exceptions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to select few elements on the web page but I want it also to contain the exceptional elements of HTML.
How can I do that?

var elementName = 'body';

For example, I want to perform some action when the **elementName** is **body, html**, but want to exclude this action if elementName is **select,div** etc.

Can I do something like:

```
$("html,body,^div,^select").css('background-color', 'blue');
```

I tried this, but it is giving error: **Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression**

Comment: not is your friend :  http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elementName` as your selector, then apply the [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method with a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$(elementName).not("div, select").css("background-color", "blue");
```